# Parallelization of torch.stack inside forwad pass

Tags: parallel-processing, neural-network, pytorch

Inside a forward pass of a Neural Network I have this snippet of code.

```
myNewTensor = th.stack([
                         self.my_function(inputA[i], inputB[i] for i in range(inputA.shape[0]) 
                                         )
                      ])
```

This is obviously embarrassingly parallel and there is no way to vectorize the function. Is there a way to parallelize this operation in pytorch while still being able to backpropagate through it?

Comment: what is `self.my_function`?

Comment: it is a custom function where I do many operations to output a vector which is then stacked with the other vectors resulting from the same function by torch.stack

Comment: is it a pure function? also, this looks like a syntax error

Comment: yes, it is a pure function. I modified a bit of the code to make it more understandable, but i works in the forward and backwards pass, just super slow and i am trying to parallelize it